# Any Approach for Case Sensitive Columns in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have requirement of having same column names but in case sensitive manner for iOS project.

For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( name TEXT, Name TEXT );
```

I know that SQLite's columns are case insensitive.

My current approach is using hash function to create unique number for each string.

```
func hashcode(columnname) -> String { }
```

I can use this hash code as my column name.

Is there any better approach for this problem?

Comment: If you need case sensitive columns then you do something really wrong in your design.

Comment: Thanks for reply @juergend.  Yes it is bad design for static tables. In my case, tables are created dynamically where my columns are defined  by users. User can give Case Sensitive column names.  If Sqlite supports this, It would be easy to implement my use case. :)

Comment: *tables are created dynamically* - that is even worse.